# Fish Shell: Check and run a process if not running

Tags: terminal, fish, mpd

I want to start a process [mpd] when I open up terminal, and check if it's already running when I open a second tab so it won't try to run it again. This is what I used to have on my .bashrc:

```
#start mpd automatically if not yet running.
if [[ -z "$(pgrep mpd)" ]]; then
  mpd
fi
```

I suppose is something like this, or maybe using `test -f`, but I can't figure out how to make it work:

```
# MPD
if pgrep mpd > /dev/null 
  command mpd
end
```

[this is located on my config.fish file].

Comment: What about using `if not pgrep -f mpd > /dev/null; command mpd; end`?

Comment: Perfect!! seems like I needed just a little bit of help. tks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could add to your `config.fish`.

```
if not pgrep -f mpd > /dev/null
    command mpd
end
```

Or if you are using fish >= `2.3.0` to `~/.config/fish/conf.d/*` for a better separation of concerns.